# One or more essential parameters were not entered powershell

Tags: powershell, firewall

I have an existing `Outbound Rule` in my **firewall** with a set of specified **IP addresses**. For enhanced security, I want to append additional IP addresses to this rule using a **shell script**. I am trying to execute the following **command**:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Outbound Rule Name" remoteip=IP_ADDRESS1,IP_ADDRESS2,...
```

However, I encounter the following **error message**:

```
One or more essential parameters were not entered. Verify the required parameters, and reenter them.
```

I initially suspected that there might be an issue with the rule itself, but when I ran the command:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Outbound Rule Name"
```

It confirmed that the rule is active and functioning. I am perplexed about what might be wrong with the add rule command and which essential parameters are missing.

Comment: You need to supply values for direction and requested action: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Outbound Rule Name" dir=out action=allow remoteip=...`

Comment: Thnak you @MathiasR.Jessen, the action I was looking for is block. A new rule was  added after executing the command, I want to update the existing one and add the new IPs, how can I do it ?

Comment: By using `set rule`, see answer below

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule ?` it'll show a nice usage text:

```
Usage: add rule name=<string>  
      dir=in|out
      action=allow|block|bypass
      [program=<program path>]
      [service=<service short name>|any]
      [description=<string>]
      [enable=yes|no (default=yes)]
      [profile=public|private|domain|any[,...]]
      [localip=any|<IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
      [remoteip=any|localsubnet|dns|dhcp|wins|defaultgateway|
         <IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
      [localport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|RPC|RPC-EPMap|IPHTTPS|any (default=any)]
      [remoteport=0-65535|<port range>[,...]|any (default=any)]
      [protocol=0-255|icmpv4|icmpv6|icmpv4:type,code|icmpv6:type,code|
         tcp|udp|any (default=any)]
      [interfacetype=wireless|lan|ras|any]
      [rmtcomputergrp=<SDDL string>]
      [rmtusrgrp=<SDDL string>]
      [edge=yes|deferapp|deferuser|no (default=no)]
      [security=authenticate|authenc|authdynenc|authnoencap|notrequired
         (default=notrequired)]
```

As you can see, the `dir=...` and `action=...` parameters are not enclosed in `[...]` in the syntax diagram *because they are **non-optional*** - so include those and the command should succeed:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Outbound Rule Name" dir=out action=allow remoteip=...
```

---

To update an existing rule, use `set rule` and reference the existing rule by name:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Outbound Rule Name" action=block
```

Comment: Can this be done using a PowerShell function and not netsh.exe? Perhaps something amongst `Get-Command -Name '*netfirew*'`?

Comment: @lit Sure, the module you'll want is the `NetSecurity` module that ships with Windows, `New-NetFirewallRule` and `Set-NetFirewallRule` respectively :)